A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "storedprocedure": System.Net.WebException:

Executed as user: usr_emanD.
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "uspCLRNotify": System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 19.20.xxx.xx:xxxx
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at  System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
System.Net.WebException:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at Notifications.com.direction.page.server.MailI4.Notify (String GUID)
at StoredProcedures.Notify(String GUID)  . [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error
6522).  The step failed.

I'm migrating my server to a new one, the previous server was physical Windows Server 2008, but the new one is Virtual on Microsoft Server 2019. I keep the same Database Server to keep my notifications executed for jobs.
But now, when I turn off the previous server and I try to run my daily notifications with the new server, it appears the following error. I want to change the Ip address that the Database Server is taking for the new Ip address of the new virtual server.
The SQL error is:

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "uspname", error with Job SQL Server

and is a stored procedure who have just an assembly, only the address to an assembly which is ServiciosWebClr2. And the only thing it has is encrypted binary code inside. I have already checked other forums where they mention that it might be in the source code, but I don’t have the old IP anywhere in the code.
Does anyone know how to solve it or had a similar situation?
I have already tried decompiling the assembly, but I can't find it anywhere on my disk, and according to comments, it is not a physical file it's just generated by SQL Server, I got
c:\\SqlClassLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll, 
c:\\SqlClassLibrary.dll, SendDataBaseMail.dll 
ServiciosWebClr2.dll

the files when I make the query search show a table with id "1" and then the content with the binary numbers. When I look for the files in the servers, it says "can't found". I try to use a Dot Peek to get the assembly and not worked, I tried to modify in the Visual Studio Code Main, without results.

Did you already ask this question? Deleting and re-asking the same question will just result in it being closed again.

As I told you in the original question, you need to take the binary value from the assembly files table and save it into your dll file and then you can try to decompile it. A PowerShell script should be able to achieve the saving me thinks.

Here's a very raw PowerShell module to get you started:
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "yourserver" -Database "yourdatabase" -Query "select content, case when name like '%\%' then right(name, charindex('\', reverse(name)) -1) else name end as name, datalength(content) as ln
from sys.assembly_files
--where assembly_id = 65539" -MaxBinaryLength 99999999

foreach ($r in $results)
{
    $r #for debugging
    Set-Content -Path $r["name"] -Value $results["content"][0..($results["ln"]-1)] -Encoding Byte
}

It fetches all assemblies and stores them into separate files, I've stripped the path part of it just in case. Then you can hopefully decompile it.
You can add the where condition to save specific files.

I use the next PowerShell
$drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Root
foreach ($drive in $drives) {
Get-ChildItem -Path $drive -Filter SqlClassLibrary.dll -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
So, I found the .dll and got the direction and data forma tables and the URL direction from the site where take the notifications, but the data is encrypted. There is a way to change the direction and ip or edit the file .dll?

I have no idea, this is at least a new question. I think you probably have more luck just reimplementing whatever you're trying to hack

Thanks mate, nothing to hack just got problems to migrate my send notifications. But thanks for the suggestions.
